# Остановка цикла при создании нового QWidget объекта

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть главное окно типа `QWidget` которое вызывает другое окно этого же класса с помощью функции `StartFunc()`:

```
void Anime::StartFunc()
{
    secondW = new Form;
    secondW->show();
    secondW->activateWindow();
    qDebug() << "Target reached";
}
```

Задача в том, чтобы после вызова метода `secondW->activateWindow();` функция остановилась, дождалась закрытия виджета `secondW` и только потом продолжила работу (вызов `qDebug() << "Target reached";`).

Мой опыт подсказывает, что нужно сделать еще один метод в объекте `secondW` которая будет крутиться и не давать закончится до тех пор, пока не придет сигнал о закрытии окна. Но мне кажется, что это костыльный метод и есть более правильное и адекватное решение. Есть ли такое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно унаследовать свое окно от `QDialog` и использовать метод [exec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec)

Comment: Да, я об этом тоже подумал

Answer (score 3):

То, что вам нужно, называется модальностью. Модальные окна - это те окна, которые делают все остальные окна неактивными и не позволяют осуществлять в них любой ввод, пока это окно не закрыто. В данном случае следует воспользоваться методом [setWindowModality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop).

```
void Anime::StartFunc()
{
    secondW = new Form;
    secondW->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    secondW->show();
    secondW->activateWindow();
    qDebug() << "Target reached";
}
```

Comment: Окно действительно становится по верх всех окон, но это не останавливает работу функции. 'qDebug() << "Target reached";' все равно выполняется.